# Should i install a VPN on Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, vpn

Is it safe to use Tor without a VPN? Or Should i install a VPN?

Comment: It completely depends on what your definition of “safe” is. But in general Tor is designed to be used by itself, and combining that with a VPN may even provide worse anonymity.

Comment: @Steve With "safe" i meant that that nobody is able to trace me. If a VPN would provide a worse anonymity then why duckduckgo browser ask me to install a VPN when i'm on duckduckgo's homepage?

Comment: Can you post the exact message it said? VPNs provide some privacy but not anonymity. Tor tries to provide both. It’s best to not mix them unless you really know what you’re doing.

Comment: Okay that’s not a VPN. They’re asking you to install a browser extension which does things like block some third party tracking requests, upgrade connections to HTTPS when possible, changes your search engine, etc. The Tor Browser already does these things with extensions like HTTPS Everywhere, NoScript, etc. You can see these at the top right of the browser in your screenshot.

Comment: not exactly your question/answer, but good information (without FUD) about VPN & Tor: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN

Answer (score 0):

Tor is itself VPN. But if you badly have second layer of protection VPN is shit. Use Proxy wich are better solution because VPN does not hide you completly. 
VPN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network
Proxy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: Tor is not a VPN, and provides much stronger anonymity than either a VPN or a classic web proxy.

Comment: @Steve We can say "kind of VPN"

Comment: It is completely different than a VPN. The designs are completely different and they’re designed for different purposes.

Comment: @Steve... boy. Define how VPN works and how Tor works.

Comment: @Cnoob **no, it is not!** and nothing needs to be defined, its a fact: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/should-i-install-a-vpn-on-tor-browser#comment20107_19370